# Flutter debug on Mac stuck on Launching

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

I am trying test my app on Mac and I've set all the configurations correctly but its hanaging on Launching for hours. No errors. The last value I set was ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3' in my pod file. How do I find out what is wrong? No error message comes up. it sits on "Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode..." for hours.

Comment: Can you share the output from `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: Andriod Studio? VS Code? Tried with different emulator/device? Remove your plugins, ```flutter clean``` and try again. Also, post your ```flutter doctor -v``` like Mahesh said so we have a better idea.

Comment: Vscode. It runs on android emulators fine

Comment: It’s now saying flutter is not a command. I set my path to the ask last night